# What would make this code that combines some flat files run faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I'm new to Python and haven't gotten into any optimization work yet. I'm attempting to take a bunch of files that themselves are already pretty large and combine them into one large file that will probably wind up being close to 50-100GB would be my guess. More memory than I have at any rate. I was given the code below and it works great for small files. When I try to run it over the actual files for my use case, it will totally lock up my computer.

I understand that Pandas is fast. I'm guessing that data frames are stored in memory. If that is the case then that is probably what is wrecking stuff up here. Is there any kind or mechanism to spill to disk or possibly write to an existing file instead of trying to hold the whole thing in a dataframe before writing to disk? Or possibly another option that I didn't think of?

```
import pandas as pd
import os

file_masks = ['fhv', 'green', 'yellow']


def combine_files(file_mask):

    csvfiles = []
    for path, directories, files in os.walk('TaxiDriveData/'):
        csvfiles.extend([os.path.join(path, fn) for fn in files if fn.startswith(file_mask)])

    df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(fn) for fn in csvfiles))
    df.to_csv(os.path.join('TaxiDriveCombinedData', file_mask + '_trip_data.csv'), index=False)

for m in file_masks:
    combine_files(m)
```

Comment: Dispense with pandas altogether if all you are using it is to parse csv's. You probably don't have to parse them at all, maybe skip a header...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a non pandas solution that doesn't load everything to memory. I haven't tested it but it should work.

```
import os

file_masks = ['fhv', 'green', 'yellow']


def combine_files(file_mask):

    with open(os.path.join('TaxiDriveCombinedData', file_mask + '_trip_data.csv'),'w') as fout:
        csvfiles = []
        for path, directories, files in os.walk('TaxiDriveData/'):
            csvfiles.extend([os.path.join(path, fn) for fn in files if fn.startswith(file_mask)])

        for in_file in csvfiles:
            with open(in_file,'r') as fin:
                # f.next() # comment this out if you want to remove the headers
                for line in fin:
                    fout.write(line)


for m in file_masks:
    combine_files(m)
```

Comment: Excellent! That worked and didn't lock up my machine on the test files. I'm going to run it over the entire data set. If that works, I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Python to do that. There are a lot of tools in a linux system that can join files and are optimized or have parameters to do this very efficiently: join, cat, dd...

This is not the most efficient option, but, for example:

```
cat input/*.csv > output/combined.csv
```

If you want a high-performance Python version I recommend you to read and write the files in chunks instead of reading the files line by line.

Your biggest problem is the I/O and you can optimize this by reading and writing larger information blocks of the hard disk. If you read and write in the optimal size of your hard drive and your filesystem you will notice the difference.
For exmaple, a common block size for newer HDDs is 4096-byte (4 KiB).

You can try something like the following:

```py
NEW_LINE = '\n'

def read_in_chunks(f, chunksize=4096):
    while True:
        chunk = f.read(chunksize)
        if not chunk:
            break
        yield chunk

(...)

fout = open('output.csv', 'w') 

for fname in files:
    with open(fname) as fin:
        buffer = ''
        for chunk in read_in_chunks(fin):
           buffer += chunk
           lines, tmp_buffer = buffer.rsplit(NEW_LINE, 1) 
           lines += NEW_LINE  # rsplit removes the last new-line char. I re-add it
           fout.write(lines)
           buffer = tmp_buffer

fout.close()
```